# Share settings between related Windows Store Apps

Tags: windows-8, settings, windows-store-apps

We are currently planning to develop a suite of Windows Store Apps. They are independent and fully work alone, but they are related and act in concert. If a user has several of them, they should share some of their settings (and data), so that the user does not have to manually change these settings in every single one of them.

Is such a scenario even intented?

And how to implement it?

- Registry: Does not work. Apps cannot access the registry.
- ApplicationData (LocalFolder, LocalSettings etc.): Does not work. Apps cannot access the data of other apps.
- Cloud services: Kind of works, but only when the machine is online. Our apps should work offline, too. And we would need to create/rent such a cloud service, which would cause additional costs.
- KnownFolder.DocumentsLibrary: This –currently– looks like the only solution to me. The apps are already saving and sharing data there, so let's just save our settings there, too. But the name of the shared folder is one of the settings! And Windows Store Apps cannot create hidden files, so the user can see the settings file. This makes this solution a bit... "rough".

Any other ideas or additional information I have missed?

Comment: Could you confirm that you are NOT asking for multiple apps on the same device to chat with each other? Though this is technically possible, the user experience is very bad since apps are generally suspended when any other app is running (except for SnapView).

Comment: If you are wanting apps to interact with each other on the same network you should look into the Proximity API which allows you to ad hoc connect multiple machines through BT or WIFI and have fun.

Comment: @JerryNixon-MSFT: No chatting. You start app A, change some shared settings and start app B. Now B should respect the changed settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want them to sync with each other instantly, even when the device is offline, then that's your only option.  Windows 8 Apps are not intended to share settings.

Comment: note too, that automatic (i.e., non user-initiated) use of the DocumentsLibrary capability does require a "business" developer license, so there's an additional hoop there. See [App Capability declarations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464936.aspx#Special_use_capabilities)

Comment: @JimO'Neil: But that's only an additional hoop for the developer, not the user, isn't it?

Comment: @SebastianNegraszus yes, the developer would need to qualify for a business account (and pay the $99 developer fee versus the $49 individual one)

Answer (score 0):

So much want of sharing.

1. Roaming API will only share with the SAME app, the SAME user, ANY W8 device.
2. SkyDrive will only share across ANY app, the SAME user, ANY device.
3. Using Azure (or any web service) will share across ANY app, ANY user, ANY device.

Don't do this

1. Don't use the register, the API is not supported
2. Don't use the file system, the boundaries cause your app to be brittle
3. Don't use ApplicationData.AnyFolder, this is restricted to a single app GUID

You had might as well get "instant" out of your language, man. That just doesn't happen. But you can have fast (let's call it near instant); you can use Sockets or SignalR to connect your client to some service out there with nearly instant responses. A less sophisticated approach would be to poll from your client, too. It has served developers for decades.

Comment: "Cloud services: Kind of works, but only when the machine is online. Our apps should work offline, too."

Comment: The best solution is to have the apps communicate with each other when they are online but not when they are offline. Otherwise it is begging for complexity and easy-to-break patterns that will make users frustrated.